# Currency converter Issue

Tags: python

I have attempted to make a currency converter, however the "while" loop doesn't work when i choose option 2 or three. Choosing option 1 is fine but the other two are broken.

```
##### Welcome Menu######
print("*************************************")
print("*  Queensmead currency converter    *")                
print("*  1) Convert from Pound to Dollar  *")
print("*  2) Conver from Dollar to Pound   *")
print("*  3) Quit                          *")
print("*                                   *")
print("*************************************")

print ("Hello, Welcome to the Currency Converter. \nWhat is your name ? ")
name = input()

userChoice= input ("Hi " + name + ", Please choose one of the above options ")

while userChoice == "1":
  #Prompt the user the amount of Pound they want to convert
  #Store what the user typed into a vairable
   userGBP = int(input ("Enter the amount in Pound Stirling you wish to convert to US Dollars: "))

   dollar = userGBP * 1.55
    #Returns the amount to user request
   print ("£",userGBP , "=", dollar ,"US Dollars")
   userChoice = input("If you like to convert some more money,please choose from the above Options  ")
   print (userChoice)



   if userChoice =="2":
   #Prompt the user the amount of Pound they want to convert
   #Store what the user typed into a variable
      userDollar = int(input ("Enter the amount in Dollars you wish to convert to Pound Stirling: "))

      pound = userDollar * 0.64
      #Returns the amount to user request
      print ("$",userDollar , "=", pound ,"Pound Stirling")
      userChoice = input("If you like to convert some more money,please choose from the above Options ")
      print (userChoice)

   elif userChoice =="3":
      userQuit = input ("")
      print ("Thank you for using this program")

   else:
    print ("Error: You have entered invalid selection. Please try again")
```

Comment: What gave you the idea of checking for option "1" with a `while` loop, and other options with `if`? Is converting dollars to pounds really that much different conceptually that they require different constructs? Please read sections about the `while` and `if` statements at any tutorial on the internet and you will understand your mistake - this implementation doesn't make much sense, and there are many other problems here.

Comment: Pretty sure this question isn't about converting currencies.

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
while userChoice == "1":
```

to:

```
while True:
```

if should be like:

```
 while True:
     #user input choice
     if use_choice == 1:
         #do_stuff
     if use_choice == 2:
         #do_stuff
     if use_choice == 3:
         break
     .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop has the condition `userChoice == "1"`; in other words, keep running the program while the user has selected the first choice, exiting on the second or third choices. Instead, you probably want it to keep running your program *until quit has been selected*. To do that, you’d need to replace the condition with `userChoice != "3"`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, i can now see the massive errors that i made.

Answer (score 0):

You code has some flaws, mostly because the user choice is linked to to the while loop, instead it should be linked to a if/elif/else condition tree:

Also, you code repeats itself a lot, it's a bad practice

```
print("*************************************")
print("*  Queensmead currency converter    *")
print("*************************************")

name = input("Hello, Welcome to the Currency Converter. \n"
                 "What is your name? ")

main_menu = """
*************************************
*  1) Convert from Pound to Dollar  *
*  2) Conver from Dollar to Pound   *
*  3) Quit                          *
*************************************"""
print(main_menu)
userChoice = input("Hi " + name + ", Please choose one of the above options: ")


def convert_to(value, ratio):
    return value * ratio


while True:
    if userChoice == "1":
        currency_from = "Pound Stirling"
        currency_to = "US Dolar"
        ratio = 1.55
    elif userChoice == "2":
        currency_to = "Pound Stirling"
        currency_from = "US Dolar"
        ratio = 0.64
    elif userChoice == "3":
        print ("Thank you for using this program")
        userQuit = input("")
        break
    else:
        print ("Error: You have entered invalid selection. Please try again")
    try:
        value = int(input("Enter the amount in %s you wish to convert to %s: " % (currency_from, currency_to)))
        converted_value = convert_to(value, ratio)
        print ("%0.2f %s = %0.2f %s" % (value, currency_from, converted_value, currency_to))
    except NameError:
         pass
    input("Press ENTER to continue")
    print main_menu
    userChoice = input("If you like to convert some more money,please choose from the above Options: ")
```

Here's a code review:

1. Changed the order of the Main menu, so the options are displayed
   after the user name is taken.
2. Made the main_menu a variable, so it can be reused later after
   converting.
3. Created a function which will handle the convertion, leaving the
   loop just to set things.
4. The loop takes the userChoice and depending on it, it will set the
   currency_from, currency_to, and the ratio between them. A break is
   set on the userChoice '3' to leave the loop.
5. The variable 'value', takes the user input, the formating is using
   string formating(the % sign), it takes the currency_to and
   currency_from.
6. converted_value sends the 'value' and the 'ratio', and catchs the
   new value
7. The converted value is displayed using again string formating.
8. The main menu is printed again
9. The try/except bit is in case the user enters a invalid option in
   the menu, it would raise a NameError because currency_from,
   currency_to and ratio wouldn't exist.